# How to resolve write timeout exception in cassandra?

Tags: java, exception, cassandra, prepared-statement, resultset

I'm trying to insert 50000 records into a five node cassandra cluster. I'm using **executeAsync** so as to increase the performance(reduce insertion time from Application side). I tried Batchstatement with several batch sizes, but everytime I got the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException.copy(WriteTimeoutException.java:54)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:259)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:175)
at
```

I inserted data i.e. 10000,20000 upto 40000 records without any issue. The following is the java code I wrote.

```
for (batchNumber = 1; batchNumber <= batches; batchNumber++) {
    BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
    for (record = 1; record <= batchSize; record++) {
        batch.add(ps.bind(query));
    }
    futures.add(session.executeAsync(batch));           
}
for (ResultSetFuture future : futures) {
    resultSet = future.getUninterruptibly();
}
```

where ps is the prepared statement, batches is number of batches, and batchSize is the number of records in a batch.

I'm unable to understand the root cause of the issue. I thought that some of the nodes were down and when I checked all are running normally.

How should I debug the exception?

Comment: are you sure all nodes are up ?

Comment: Even if i'm not, consistency level is one right, so it does not need all nodes to be up nah

Comment: what version of cassandra are you using?

Answer (score 5):

I see a few mistakes:

1. It seems you are trying to figure out what is the *largest* number of queries you can *batch* together.
2. It seems you are thinking that *batching* multiple statements will give you some sort of performance gain.
3. You are mistakenly *reusing the same* prepared statement in the loop.
4. You are not *throttling* your application at *some* ingestion rate.
5. You are not performing *any* exception handling, eg retrying when some batch fails.

Let's restart.

---

1. The maximum number of statements in a batch should be less than 10. The lesser the better. And by the way, the total size of the batch *must* be lower than whatever value there's in the YAML configuration file. Usually, if your batches are larger than 5kb then a warning will appear in your logs. If your batches gets larger than 50kb the batches will fail. You can tune these values, but you should keep in mind that a `BATCH` overloads the coordinator node. The larger the batch (both in term of kb or number of statements), the greater the overload on the coordinator.
2. You won't gain anything from batching unrelated statements together. Instead, you'll actually *lose* performance. This is due to how the `BATCH` works. One node is chosen to *coordinate* all the statements, and such node will be responsible for *all* the statements. Usually the coordinator is chosen based on the first statement, and if your statements hit multiple nodes, your coordinator will need to coordinate things belonging to different nodes as well. Instead, if you'd fire multiple *separate* async queries, every node would be responsible for *their* statements only. You'd be spreading the *overload* on all your cluster nodes instead of hammering on one node.
3. You are using prepared statements in a wrong way. You should add a `new BoundStatement(ps).bind(xxxx)` statement. That's an easy fix anyway.
4. If you have a large number of queries to run, you are running them all the way long. You're going to exhaust your application memory because it will keep adding `future`s to the list, and will be eventually be killed because an OOM error. Moreover, you're not giving your cluster the possibility to actually *ingest* all the data you're firing at it, because you can fire data way faster than your cluster can ingest. What you need to do is *limit* the number of futures in the list. Keep it to *some* value at most (eg say 1000). To perform such task you need to move your final loop with `.getUninterruptibly` *inside* the loop. This way, you throttle down the ingestion rate and will see a decreased timeout exceptions count. And depending on the application, decreased timeout exceptions means less retries, hence less queries, less overhead, better response times etc...
5. It is fine to have a loop with `.getUninterruptibly` on the `Future`'s list, but what you should keep in mind that when your cluster is 
   overloaded, you **will** get timeouts. At this point, you should catch the exception and **deal** with it, be it a retry, be it a re-throw, be it whatever else. I suggest you to design you model around *idempotent* queries, so I can retry the failed queries until they succeed without worrying about retry consequences (which can happen at driver level too!).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. So, I understand that I'm firing data       faster than what cluster can ingest into itself. Insertion of 50000 records was happening without any issues when session.execute() is used(not executeAsync() ). Is it because, data is inserted sequentially so that cluster is not pressurized with data?

Comment: Indeed `.execute()` will wait until the `BATCH` is processed, limiting to just one statement to be executed by the coordinator.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what `BATCH` is for.
When you add multiple statements to a batch, Cassandra will try to apply them atomically.
Either all of them will succeed or none of them will, and they all have to complete within a single query timeout.

Also, if you make more requests than can be handled simultaneously, they're going to go into a queue, and time waiting in the queue contributes to the timeout.

To get them all through without timeout, use individual statements and limit the number in flight at any one time.
Alternatively, use a [`COPY`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) command to load the data from a CSV.